# How to simulate 'click' action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript. Learning and implementing with the help of Google and Stack Overflow. I have written a snippet to select an element form drop down. But instead of selecting, I need an click event there.

```
function Selected(sel){
            console.log(sel.value)
            var $default_value = jQuery('.setting-main').eq(1).find('option')
            var $i = 0
            for ($i=0; $i< ($default_value).length ; $i++){
                if(sel.value == $default_value[$i].value){
                    $default_value[$i].selected= true  //This selects the value
                    // Instead of selecting. How to simulate the "Click" event/action
                }
                else{
                    $default_value[$i].selected= false
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` button in the editor and provide a [mcve] - remember to click TIDY before saving. Also please tell us what you want to achieve rather than what you think will achieve it. Lastly please reserve the $xxx to jQuery variables - the $i is confusingly looking like a PHP var

Comment: You should read the jQuery docs. If $default_value is the option element you want to click then do $default_value.click()

Comment: @Jerinaw: I tried that, $default_value[$i].click(); but didn't work.

Comment: There are many things in your script that are confusing. Why would you loop when you can get $("setting-main :selected") for an array of selected values from all dropdowns. Also if you want to select the default-selected have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/5270575/295783

Comment: i think select boxes fire change events not clicks. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: You should only try to fire clicks on selects if you are trying to open the drop down programatically. Otherwise use change - also you cannot set a selected option to false. Instead choose the first option if you have a "Please select"

Comment: @mplungjan: I understand your concern. By default, few dropdowns available. I'm providing interface by creating above GUI, which will be linked to already available dropdowns. Already available dropdowns work perfectly, like if i select any item rest all drop downs will be activated. But when i provide the GUI interface, selecting GUI element selects an item in dropdown bt rest GUI interfaces will not be activated accordingly.

Comment: This works https://plnkr.co/edit/WE8utCtfacxZOIOh1FpE?p=preview

Comment: You can just use jQuery click() method `$default_value[$i].click()` https://api.jquery.com/click/